# Object name to String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to get object name to String, but i don't have idea how to do that

I have object with sub-objects like this:

```
var tempForm = {
      name : {...},
      age : {...},
      e-mail : {...}
 }
```

Then i've got function where I need to return htmlElement with id like object name in argument

```
 function get(obj){
    return document.getElementById(// get obj name //);
 }
```

So for example:

```
 test = get(tempForm.age);
```

Should return HTMLObject 
     < input id="age" >

Comment: age is an object (JSON) of your object tempForm but not a string

Comment: Your function get have no sense, you could acces via tempForm.* where * it's the key String (name, eago, e-mail...)

Comment: @Tit-oOo — It is not JSON. JSON is a data format. This is JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `get(tempForm.age)` will pass the **value** of `tempForm.age`. There will be no connection to the string `"age"` at all.

The general way to achieve this is to put the data you care about in the object.

```
var tempForm = {
  name: {
    element_id: "name"
  },
  age: {
    element_id: "age"
  },
  "e-mail": {
    element_id: "e-mail"
  }
}
```

and

```
function get(obj){
    return document.getElementById(obj.element_id);    
}
```

Alternatively, if you **know** that the `tempFrom` variable contains the "parent" object **and** `tempForm` is in scope for the `get` function then you can loop over `tempForm` and look for a match for the value that was passed in. This isn't a nice way to solve the problem though and you'd be better off structuring your data better or just passing the string `"age"` explicitly in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

i'd rewrite your function like:

```
function getSomething(obj, propName) {
    //and then access property like
    var propObject = obj[propName];
    //....
}
```

if you call it `test = getSomething(tempForm, "age");`
you'd have in function:

```
obj == tempForm
propName == "age"
propObject == {... age object of tempForm}
```